# Provide SSL certificate for internal Website

Tags: ssl, networking, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a website in my local network and the website is not ssl secured.
Many clients can not reach the website because of
"ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Is there any way to secure websites in a local network with ssl? I am using an Active Directory Server in my network.

There are also a lot of local Websites on a vmware that are not secured. I would like to secure them easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•   I would suggest you to please install **ADCS (Active Directory Certificate Services)** role in your Active Directory and create a **self-signed SSL certificate** through it for your internal use. Since, Active Directory is a trusted public key authentication infrastructure provider, the concerned role installed on it for the said purpose does not need certificates from globally trusted CA (certification authority) and can be thus, used locally. For the time being, if you want to create a self-signed SSL certificate on the concerned server, you will have to install **‘Web Server (IIS)’** role and then open the **‘IIS manager’** console from where you can generate the SSL self-signed certificate and bind the same to the website on that server itself. For this process, kindly refer to the link below which explains in detail the steps to be followed for generating a self-signed certificate and binding it to a website: -

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-windows-10

Please note that the above stated process is for that server on which the website is hosted locally. Thus, the self-signed certificate generated will not be useful on other servers in your environment.

•   To generate an SSL certificate for a web service/website that is hosted on a cluster of servers configured for the same purpose/website, then you will have to configure an SSL certificate template from a root CA, in your case, an AD server installed with ADCS role will serve as a root CA in your domain environment. Then assign that template to the CA (AD server in your case) for it to authorize the issuing of the configured SSL template to the concerned server where the website for which this SSL certificate is to be installed is hosted. For more detailed information regarding this, please refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn781428(v=ws.11)#obtain-an-ssl-certificate-from-ad-cs

Please note that the above link states the issuing of the SSL certificate for an ADFS Server. You will need to change the Subject Name of the issued certificate to that website for which you are issuing this certificate.